# What do the Q do with their time?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-q

I know this seems like a bit of confusing question. But imagine the situation when you know everything that is to know in the Universe, and you have already seen all of the places.

So, what is the purpose of Q like beings in the Universe? They cannot even interact with lower species because they already know what's going to happen. I say that because Q himself had mentioned time is not linear.

Isn't that kind of boring, just to sit around, fool around throughout the universe, or was that the point when Q as species was introduced in ST.

Imagine a life where you have nothing to know/learn/look forward to. The excitement, the curiosity, learning process, failure, etc they all go out of the airlock as soon as I think about the Q. I see the Q continuum and Q individuals in that fashion.

So, my question is, what do they actually do rather than fooling around with other species, which makes no sense as the Q already would know the outcome.

Comment: It's so boring that one of their foremost thinkers is contemplating suicide; http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Death_Wish_(episode)

Comment: @Richard Death Wish, I know. One of my fav ST:VOY episode.

Comment: I'm confused what you're asking. There's an entire episode that basically answers this.

Comment: @Richard : Is there something else the Q do other than fooling around? and what they think their purpose is?

Comment: *"So, what is the purpose of Q like beings in the Universe?"*  Mess with people's heads for the laughs?   *"They cannot even interact with lower species because they already know what's going to happen. I say that because Q himself had mentioned time is not linear."*  Just because you have the *ability* to flit through time to discover anything you like, doesn't mean you'll necessarily do that..

Comment: This comes down to "what is the meaning of life?". Beyond what we saw in _Death Wish_ I have no idea what sort of answer you're expecting here.

Comment: *So, what is the purpose of Q like beings in the Universe?* "I have given pleasure to the world because I have such a beautiful ass." - [The Cat, *The Inquisitor*, *Red Dwarf*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0684182/quotes)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is, **not a lot**, because they've already done *everything*.

According to the Q known as Quinn, at the beginning of what he describes as the "New Era", the Q reveled in their newfound powers and explored the entire universe. They evidently brought back their discoveries to the continuum where they would be discussed and digested at length.

Unfortunately, an infinity of life has taken its toll on the Q. Now mostly they just sit around, going through the motions, ensuring that lesser races follow their allotted paths and don't get out of place. Occasionally one of their number goes a bit doolally and they're forced to intervene but this is apparently quite a rare occurrence:

> **Q2:** *And it was wonderful. For a while. At the beginning of the new
>   era, life as a Q was one continuous dialogue of discovery and issues
>   and humor from all over the universe... but look at them now... listen
>   to their dialogue now...*
>
> **TUVOK:** *I am afraid I cannot hear any.*
>
> **Q2:** *Because it's all been said. Everyone has seen everything, heard
>   everything. They haven't had to speak to each other for ten millennia.
>   There's nothing left to say.* - <sub><sup>[Voy: Death Wish](http://www.st-minutiae.com/academy/literature329/voy034.txt)</sup></sub>

Much of the Q's "purpose" (or at least their actions) are simply unfathomable to us lesser mortals. The metaphor that Quinn uses is that he's spent some time as a scarecrow, just because he hadn't done it before. Whether this relates to some time period spent guarding the galaxy or in self-enforced solitude isn't clear. What is clear is that the Q are **bored, bored, bored**. They lack purpose and direction as a people and are essentially in terminal decline, or would be if they weren't immortal:

> **Q2:** (acknowledges) *I traveled the road many times. Sat on the porch ... played the games... been the dog... everything. I was even
>   the scarecrow for a while.*
>
> **JANEWAY:** *Why?*
>
> **Q2:** *Because I hadn't done it.*
>
> **Q1:** *Oh, we've all done the scarecrow, big deal.* - <sub><sup>[Voy: Death Wish](http://www.st-minutiae.com/academy/literature329/voy034.txt)</sup></sub>

Comment: "You're a Q. You can do anything you want." - Dr. Crusher to Amanda Rogers, [TNG Ep. 6x06: True Q](http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/True_Q_(episode))